# Scipy: excessive odeint work

Tags: scipy, ode

I have a first order ODE system: `f(x) = x_i ** 2 - x_i` for all `i` (I'm working on 3 dimensions for now).

This is how I've defined it:

```
lower, upper = -10, 10

def xdot(__xs, t):
    return [__xs[i] ** 2 - __xs[i] for i in range(len(__xs))]

x0 = [1.2, 1.2, 1.2]
t = np.linspace(lower, upper, upper - lower)
res = integrate.odeint(xdot, x0, t)
```

Is this the correct way of using odeint? I get:
`ODEintWarning: Excess work done on this call`

Comment: You might have better luck researching over on Computational Science. What research have you done? e.g.: https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/q/15835

Comment: for value > 1, the derivative is positive i.e. the values are going to increase, the function is not stable here

Comment: @xdze2 thanks you can make it an answer please

Comment: It works without any error for me... `python 3.6.1`

Comment: @Bazingaa: Can you then plot it over the full interval [-10, 10]?

Answer (score 0):

Your use of the ODE solver is correct.

---

The solution of `x' = x^2-x=x*(x-1)` is

```
(1/x)'=-x'/x^2 = -1+1/x
1/x = C*e^t + 1  ==> C = (1/x0 - 1)*e^(-t0)
x(t) = x0 / ( (1-x0)*e^(t-t0) + x0)
```

and in the case that `x0 > 1` the denominator has a root at `t = t0 + ln(x0) - ln(x0-1)`.

For `x0 = 1.2` this happens at `t=t0+1.7917594`, while your integration interval has length `20`. Close to this point function value and derivative grow very large, thus driving the internal step size down to compensate. The high number of integration steps with small step size leads to the error message "Excess work done". If you remove that by increasing the `mxstep` parameter you will then get the error that the step size is too small to advance the time by floating point addition.