# Solving system of ODEs in python; excess work done on this call

Tags: python, ode, odeint

I am trying to solve a system of coupled ODEs in python for different potentials. It works for a particular type of potential (exponential) but once the potential is described by a power law, the graph produced by python is not at all coherent and it frequently just assigns zero value to all arguments. My coding works for:

```
kr1 = 8*np.pi
#rho_m = a**(-3)
#V = np.e**(-kr1*x_1)
#dVdx = -kr1*np.e**(-kr1*x_1)

def quintessence (x, t):
    a = x[0]
    x_1 = x[1]
    x_2 = x[2]
    dadt = (kr1*a/np.sqrt(3))*np.sqrt(1/2 * x_2**2 + np.e**(-kr1*x_1) + a**(-3))
    dx_1dt = x_2
    dx_2dt = -np.sqrt(3)*kr1*np.sqrt(1/2 * x_2**2 + np.e**(-kr1*x_1) + a**(-3))*x_2 + kr1*np.e**(-kr1*x_1)

    return[dadt, dx_1dt, dx_2dt]

x0 = [0.0001, 0, 0]
t = np.linspace(0, 80, 1000)

x = odeint(quintessence, x0, t)

a = x[:,0]
x_1 = x[:,1]
x_2 = x[:,2]

plt.plot(t, a)
plt.show()
```

It doesnt work for (and prints a RuntimeWarning message):

```
kr1 = 8*np.pi
#rho_m = a**(-3)
#V = M**2*x_1**(-2) with M=1
#dVdx = -2M**2*x_1**(-3) 

def quintessence2 (x, t):
    a = x[0]
    x_1 = x[1]
    x_2 = x[2]
    V = x_1**(-2)
    dVdx_1 = -2*x_1**(-3)
    dadt = (kr1*a/np.sqrt(3))*np.sqrt((1/2) * x_2**2 + V + a**(-3))
    dx_1dt = x_2
    dx_2dt = -np.sqrt(3)*kr1*np.sqrt((1/2) * x_2**2 + V + a**(-3))*x_2 + dVdx_1    
    return [dadt, dx_1dt, dx_2dt]

x0 = [.0001, 0.01, 0.01]
t = np.linspace(1, 80, 1000)

x = odeint(quintessence2, x0, t)

a = x[:,0]
x_1 = x[:,1]
x_2 = x[:,2]

plt.plot(t, a)
plt.show()
```

Any idea what may be wrong with the second piece of coding? I am relatively new to python and I don't know its limitations.

Comment: What is the RuntimeWarning message?

Comment: Please use `np.exp(u)` instead of `np.e**u`. Could you try with a de-singularized third power, instead of `u**(-3)` use `u/(eps+u**4)` for `eps=1e-4` or `1e-8`? Does the integration then carry through?

Comment: Could it be that you have a sign error, that the last term should be `...-dVdx_1`?

Comment: @LutzLehmann when I tried de-singularized third power 'ODEintWarning: Excess accuracy requested (tolerances too small). Run with full_output = 1 to get quantitative information.' message. and another message of 'RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in sqrt
  del sys.path[0]'

Comment: @LutzLehmann In the original equation there is indeed ` -dVdx_1` but as you can see, when I defined dVdx_1 I put the minus sign there.

Comment: If the term under the root is in any way expected to be a constant (energy) along the solution curves, there are some other defects in the model. Can you say something about the genesis of the system?

Comment: This is not correct semantically. The minus sign in `dVdx_1` is the result of the derivative, of the negative exponent, so if you wanted to compensate there should be no sign, but then it should not be denoted as derivative.

Comment: On the error message, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51861963/scipy-excessive-odeint-work. I thought I recently wrote a more general statement on this... You have to check if the term under the root becomes excessively small or if one of the variables grows over all bounds.

Comment: Yes, it works for the derivative with a minus sign. I will go over the module and check if I didnt make any mistakes in derivations of the equations. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

The quintessence dark energy model (see [physics.SE](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/276768/exact-solutions-of-quintessence-models-of-dark-energy) as an arbitrary reference) is

```
x'' + 3*H*x' + V'(x) = 0

H = a'/a
```

Here, from what is written,

```
H = kr1/sqrt(3) * sqrt(E) with

E = 0.5*x'^2 + V(x) + a^(-3)

(( which leads to
   E' = x'*(x''+V'(x)) - 3*a^(-4)*a' = - 3*H*x'^2 -3*a^(-3)*H 
      = -3*H*(x'^2+a^(-3))
))
```

I would implement this system in exactly these parts, as

```
def V(x): return ...
def dV(x): return ...

def quintessence(u,t):
    a,x,dx = u
    E = 0.5*dx**2 + V(x) + a**-3
    H = kr1/3**0.5 * E**0.5
    da = a*H
    ddx = -3*H*dx -dV(x)
    return [da, dx, ddx]
```